# How do I bring back an ally required for a quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have a quest from the Thieves Guild. I must investigate his house, getting passed the guard named Vald. I did a small quest to get him to move. I went to his location and found his body on the floor outside. How to I get him back to open the barred door to the house?

Comment: did you kill him?

Comment: His body should have the key, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 5):

If his body hasn't disappeared, he *should* have the key on him.

But there are other ways to do it even if that doesn't work. On the back of the house there is a lever you can hit with an arrow that will cause a ramp to the top story to unfold. The door up there just has an expert lock.

There's a [YouTube video demonstrating both of the above](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GeUue0S-rk) (warning: the house's owner is a spoiler).

Comment: ok nvm bout this, I used Whirlwind sprint on the roof of another house to get to the high door on mercers house, but ty anyway.